# Word that means "flying" but in the sense of "growing" and "not to give up" and "be free"

Tags: translation, word-requests

I was looking for a word in Japanese that means "flying"/"fly" but I wanted it to be a metaphor for "growing" and "not giving up" and "be free". Something along those lines. Since Japanese has so many words for the same concept (I am almost a total noob in Japanese) I am kinda lost.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I think it's a stretch to suggest that "flying" is a metaphor for "growing" and "not giving up" in English. I suppose "being free" works, but why do you expect there to be an equivalent Japanese word that encompasses all these ideas?  Have you done some research that suggests there is a word? What did you find?

Answer (score 2):

I consider the word 巣立つ (すｰだ-つ) quit fitting. 巣 means "nest", and 立つ stands for "stand" (HA!). It literally means the little birds grow up and flew away, and is used to say that "the youngs grew, and now are away from the elders grasp", or "became independent" in short.